# how to get the output in list as expected

Tags: python-3.x

how to find the output from the list1 when reversed it should be excluded from the output

example:
32 reverse is 23 which is already in list l1 so that should be excluded. Similarly 98 reverse is 89 hence output shud be as below.

```
l1=[32,48,98,76,23,89]



output as  [48,76]
```

tried this

```
l2=[]
x=[str(x) for x in l1]
print(x)      

for var in x:
    print(var,var[::-1])
```

o/p as below

```
32 23
48 84
98 89
76 67
23 32
89 98
```

if the reverse 32 is 23 then exclude it..

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please share your code to see where you are having difficulty. It will be easier to help guide you to your solution.

Comment: l2=[]
x=[str(x) for x in l1]
print(x)      

for var in x:
    print(var,var[::-1])

Comment: Please edit the question and enter the code in the question and please explain what is not working in your code.

Comment: What happens for the case where your list looks likes this: `l1=[32, 48, 98, 76, 48, 23, 23, 89, 89]`

Comment: stil my code is not correct .. how can we solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have successfully reversed the items in the input list.
Now all you need to do is check if the reversed items are present in the input list or not. If not, then append those items to an output list.
Try this.

```
l1=[32,48,98,76,23,89, 470, 74]
l2=[]
x=[str(x) for x in l1]
print(x)      
out = []
for var in x:
    # print(var,var[::-1])
    if int(var[::-1]) not in l1:
        out.append(int(var))

print(out) #[48, 76, 74]
```

Another approach without typecasting to string is below:

```
l1=[32,48,98,76,23,89, 470, 74]
out = []
for num in l1:
    rev = 0
    curr = num
    while curr >0:
        rev = rev*10+curr%10
        curr = curr//10

    if rev not in l1:
        out.append(num)
print(out) # [48, 76, 74]
```

Note that both these approaches work only when the list contains whole numbers only.
Also this will also work for a number that ends in 0.
For example: if the input list contains 470 and 74, then 470 will be excluded from the output.
As reverse of '470' = '074' and int('074') = 74, hence this item will be excluded.

Comment: But the original list will be integers. So, you will end up having `470` and `74`. Should the reverse of `470` actually match `74`? If I add `470` and `74` to your code, the result ends up being `[470, 48, 76, 74]`.

Comment: @idjaw it depends on OPs use case. I think that the reverse of integer 470 should be integer 74. and hence 470 should be excluded from output but 74 should not. As reverse of 74 is 47. 
Thanks for pointing this out.
I have updated my answer to reverse without typecasting to string, which should work better.

Comment: l1=[12,21,11] if we give this input the above code does n't give output of 11.. it gives empty list..